# How do you use projectDir in jvmFlags for appengineRun in Gradle?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I'm trying to use the projectDir Gradle property when specifying the path for my appEngine local datastore. I thought this would work:

```
appengine {
    run {
        jvmFlags = [
            "-Xdebug", 
            "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9998",
            "-Ddatastore.backing_store=$projectDir/dev/db.bin"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried using $projectDir, ${projectDir}, $project.projectDir, and ${project.projectDir}, but none seem to work. They either throw a *java.lang.ArrayStoreException (no error message)* error or simply use the actual string specified (eg. *${projectDir}/dev/db.bin*) as the path for the datastore.

How do I reference the Gradle project directory path for a jvmFlags parameter when using Google's appengine plugin (appengine-gradle-plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the projectDir Gradle property inside the jvmFlags array, you have to coerce the literal using the property into a string. Perhaps someone else knows exactly why since the source for the plugin uses a List type for the jvmFlags property in the plugin task. In any event, I basically added the toString() method to the end of the literal as shown below.

```
appengine {
    run {
        jvmFlags = [
            "-Xdebug", 
            "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9998",
            "-Ddatastore.backing_store=$projectDir/dev/db.bin".toString()
        ]
    }
}
```